# Way to determine the visible size of the web page

Tags: browser, visible, area

Is there a way for knowing what size was the visible portion of a page?

Are there any services that provide this? I mean, not just screen resolution, but available browser area. When a user has a lot of browser toolbars the area left for the webpage gets reduced. On the other hand, using Chrome may maximize the available space.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Javascript, you can get the Window.InnerHeight & .InnerWidth

Comment: This is often called the "viewport".

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Javascript or JQuery to do so.

Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code) (answered) question

Answer (score 1):

I found another implementation on StackOverflow itself which used jQuery.

```
$(window.top).width()  
$(window.top).height()
```

P.S. Just don't forget the brackets as i always missed them.

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7008807

Comment: Please provide referencing links when you're using information gathered from other posts. Doing so reflects positively on you by the Stack Overflow community.