# Visible window height instead of $(window).height();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to get the visible height of the whole page from inside an `iframe`, `$(window).height()` gives me the `iframe`s height?

Comment: What do you mean by "visible height"? `$(window).height()` gives you the height of the view pane.

Comment: $(window).height() works better as it's cross-browser. I.e., your answer is better :).

Comment: I need the browsers visible height, and not the height of the document. I have an `iframe` which height is set to 3500px, and if I try to get the `$(window).height();` it just gives me 3500px;

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are using frames, you can get the height of the outermost window by using `window.top` in the jQuery constructor.  The height of [`window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) will get the height of the browser window.

```
$(window.top).height();
```

Edit: Updated window.top reference as Mozilla moved their documentation around.

Comment: Note - this won't work if the frames are in two different domains, such as with Facebook apps.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work in jsFiddle when running `window.top.innerWidth` within the `result` frame in chrome developer tools console:  `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame`.  I suppose the `top` window is at domain `https://jsfiddle.net`.

Comment: doesn't work with HTML 4.01 in Chrome

Answer (score 30):

I have always used this [implementation](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)

`window.innerHeight or document.body.clientHeight or document.documentElement.­clientHeight` depending on the browser.

But i don't see why jquery's $(window).height() wont work for your visible height ?

Comment: It's because I use it within an `iFrame` on a Facebook App. The `iFrame`it self if 3500px height, but I just want to know the users window height.

Comment: None of those work. It gives me the height of the `iFrame` and not the height of the browsers visible area.

Comment: since you are in an iframe. the window object will only reference your  page. the parent page will have a different window object. And I think cross domain problems will prevent you from acessing the data :( . There must be a way facebook gives u the total height no ?

Answer (score 1):

I had cause to address a similiar issue today, because in FF `screen.height` and `window.innerHeight` return the same value, and of course my first response was to check for solutions on SO.  In the end this is how I addressed the matter, and I'm posting the longwinded version here for posterity only...

```
function visibleWindowHeight( callback ) {
    /* create temporary element 'tmp' */
    var vpHeight,
        tmp = document.createElement('div');

    tmp.id = "vp_height_px";

    /* tmp height = viewport height (100vh) */
    tmp.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;" +
        "top:0;" +
        "left:-1px;" +
        "width:1px;" +
        "height:100vh;");

    /* add tmp to page */
    document.body.appendChild(tmp);

    /* get tmp height in px */
    vpHeight = document.getElementById("vp_height_px").clientHeight;

    /* clean up */
    document.body.removeChild(tmp);

    /* pass value to callback and continue */
    callback( vpHeight );
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    visibleWindowHeight( function( visibleHeight ) {

        console.log("visibleHeight:", visibleHeight);
        /*
            ... continue etc etc  ...
        */
    });

}, !1);
```

It might help someone, sometime.