# Internet Explorer innerHeight

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can you get the window.innerHeight in internet explorer. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get browser width using javascript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.getWinSize= function(){
    if(window.innerWidth!= undefined){
        return [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    }
    else{
        var B= document.body, 
        D= document.documentElement;
        return [Math.max(D.clientWidth, B.clientWidth),
        Math.max(D.clientHeight, B.clientHeight)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Should'nt it be `Math.min()` instead of `Math.max()`? At least this seems to be the behavior you'd want in ie7 and ie8.

Answer (score 4):

A simple one line solution:

```
var WinHeight = window.innerHeight || Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.body.clientHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in IE9:

```
document.body.clientHeight
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way in IE7 & IE8.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say it should work in IE6+.  I only tested it in IE9. kennebec's solution is definitely more thorough although I've personally used document.documentElement before.

Answer (score 0):

In ie9, **window.innerHeight** and **document.body.clientHeight** only works when the content is higher than the document window.

A reliable solution is to use the [**vw** and **vh**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) css properties.

css (easy) way :

```
/* foce the content to be at 100% with css */
html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

js way :

```
// make a fitted htmlelement and returns its size.
var get_ie_size=function(){
    var domtest = document.createElement('div');
    domtest.style.display="block";
    domtest.style.width="100vw";
    domtest.style.height="100vh";
    document.body.appendChild(domtest);
    var size = [domtest.offsetWidth,domtest.offsetHeight];
    document.body.removeChild(domtest);
    return size;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way it to use jQuery. [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/height/) some detailed information on it.