# window.innerHeight ie8 alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have some calculations that rely on `window.innerHeight`. But as I have found out this is not available in any IE before IE9.  All the other options I have looked at don't even come close to the figure I get when I use `window.innerHeight`.

Does anybody have a work around?

Comment: This problem has been solved in several libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). Rather than solving it yourself, you might consider leveraging the work of others so you can focus on writing code that's specific to your requirements. Alternately, see how they do it and use that code even if you don't use the library.

Comment: This was answered before some time ago. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864467/internet-explorer-innerheight)

Comment: Except that iOS `$(window).height()` and `window.innerHeight` return different values. So I would say the problem has yet to be solved in such libraries and warrants asking.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Or can use [jQuery's `.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method:

```
$(window).height();
```

Comment: +1 `document.body.clientHeight` didn't work for me in all scenarios, but I found `$(window).height()` to be reliable

Comment: Dan is right, the real equivalent to `$(window).height()` is `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, not the `document.body.clientHeight`. Here is testing fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzdcx/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/tzdcx/1/show (works well with IE7 and above)

Answer (score 14):

I made a simple shim for IE8 and others:

- `window.innerWidth`
- `window.innerHeight`
- `window.scrollX`
- `window.scrollY`
- `document.width`
- `document.height`

**559 bytes**

```
(function(d,b){var c=b.documentElement;var a=b.body;var e=function(g,h,f){if(typeof g[h]==="undefined"){Object.defineProperty(g,h,{get:f})}};e(d,"innerWidth",function(){return c.clientWidth});e(d,"innerHeight",function(){return c.clientHeight});e(d,"scrollX",function(){return d.pageXOffset||c.scrollLeft});e(d,"scrollY",function(){return d.pageYOffset||c.scrollTop});e(b,"width",function(){return Math.max(a.scrollWidth,c.scrollWidth,a.offsetWidth,c.offsetWidth,a.clientWidth,c.clientWidth)});e(b,"height",function(){return Math.max(a.scrollHeight,c.scrollHeight,a.offsetHeight,c.offsetHeight,a.clientHeight,c.clientHeight)});return e}(window,document));
```

For updates, take a look at this gist: [yckart/9128d824c7bdbab2832e](https://gist.github.com/yckart/9128d824c7bdbab2832e)

```
(function (window, document) {

  var html = document.documentElement;
  var body = document.body;

  var define = function (object, property, getter) {
    if (typeof object[property] === 'undefined') {
      Object.defineProperty(object, property, { get: getter });
    }
  };

  define(window, 'innerWidth', function () { return html.clientWidth });
  define(window, 'innerHeight', function () { return html.clientHeight });

  define(window, 'scrollX', function () { return window.pageXOffset || html.scrollLeft });
  define(window, 'scrollY', function () { return window.pageYOffset || html.scrollTop });

  define(document, 'width', function () { return Math.max(body.scrollWidth, html.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, html.offsetWidth, body.clientWidth, html.clientWidth) });
  define(document, 'height', function () { return Math.max(body.scrollHeight, html.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.offsetHeight, body.clientHeight, html.clientHeight) });

  return define;

}(window, document));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use following in your `document.ready` and define `innerHeight` explicitly.

```
window.innerHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript method to get full window height..:**

```
window.outerHeight;
```

**Javascript methods to get full document height..:**

```
document.body.clientHeight;
```

or

```
document.body.offsetHeight;
```

**Javascript methods to get visible document area height..:**

this is height of window without bars.

```
window.innerHeight;
```

**jQuery methods to get visible document area height and window without bars area height too..:**

```
$(window).height();
```

or

```
$(window).outerHeight();
```

**jQuery methods to get full document height..:**

```
$(document).height();
```

or

```
$(document).outerHeight();
```

that's all, I hope will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I searched on because n o n e  of the here posted functions seemed to work, i always got the windowviewheight not the documents full height...

this works in all browsers I've tested...also iexplore 8:

```
var D = document;
var myHeight = Math.max(
    D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
);

alert(myHeight);
```

Comment: Where all else failed, this got it for me. Thanks!