# having an issue with IE8 - with a script that works on the other browsers perfectly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

So i have the following script that basically adjust the position of an element on the screen.

it works perfectly on the other browsers but cause an error on IE8

Here is the whole function call that causes the problem

```
function ajax_load(){
    var screenwidth = window.innerWidth
    var screenheight = window.innerHeight;
    var current_width = 250;
    var current_height = 70;
    var left = (screenwidth - current_width)/2;
    var bottom = (screenheight - current_height)/2;

    var secondajaxloaderElement = document.getElementById('ajax_loader');
    secondajaxloaderElement.style.bottom = bottom + 'px'; // Line 308 - problematic line 
    secondajaxloaderElement.style.left = left + 'px';
}
```

Any idea why would this fail on IE ?

The error i get from developer tool is :
Invalid argument. and a line number(308) which point to 
`secondajaxloaderElement.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';`

Comment: Which line does the "Invalid argument" refer to?

Comment: "top" is not defined in your code above

Comment: My personal experience with IE is that line numbers can't always be trusted. Take 'em with a grain of salt.

Comment: it refers to `secondajaxloaderElement.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';`

Comment: Are you loading some scripts with AJAX? Browsers will not be able to point the error line of a script loaded with AJAX and will notice error in false location

Comment: This just named ajax ignore that. its just a ajaxloader box that i am centering on the screen. its not loading anything from ajax @Tyson and sdespoint I've corrected my message.

Comment: Are bottom and left defined in your css for secondajaxloaderElement ?

Comment: this element has no css i am trying to define its position using style.bottom = ... and style.left = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thoses are not supported in IE8:

```
var screenwidth = window.innerWidth
var screenheight = window.innerHeight;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

See this post :

[window.innerHeight ie8 alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173236/window-innerheight-ie8-alternative)

This should work in IE8:

```
var screenwidth = document.body.clientWidth;
var screenheight = document.body.clientHeight;
```

Or you could also use jQuery with :

```
var screenwidth = $(window).width;
var screenheight = $(window).height;
```

Comment: Thank philippe . well clientheight and ().height(); both aren't 100% reliable. i guess i'll have to deal with IE9 and up

Comment: I think document.body.clientHeight and document.body.clientWidth should do it fine

Comment: yea i am aware of the Jquery .height or width - both are pretty reliable but in some cases aren't so i decided to use the innerheight with seem to be reliable always. clientWidth seems to cause problems with FF .. either way there seem to be too many issues with IE8.. even jquery UI throws many errors .. I'll try sticking to IE9 hopefully will be better. Thanks philippe