# jQuery widthRatio returning NaN on IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have fullscreen site. When I click to my page, image resize fullscreen directly. It's working on IE 9-10, Chrome, Firefox. But don't working on IE8.

My JS code:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
    $("#backgrounds img").each(function (k, v) {
        $backgroundImg = $(this);

        windowWidth = window.innerWidth
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight
        imageWidth = 1366
        imageHeight = 900

        widthRatio = windowWidth / imageWidth;
        heightRatio = windowHeight / imageHeight;

        console.log('width: ' + widthRatio)
        console.log('height: ' + heightRatio)

        if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            $backgroundImg.width(windowWidth);
            $backgroundImg.height(imageHeight * widthRatio);
        } else {
            $backgroundImg.height(windowHeight);
            $backgroundImg.width(imageWidth * heightRatio);
        }
        $backgroundImg.css({ marginLeft: -$backgroundImg.width() / 2 });
        $backgroundImg.css({ left: "50%" });
    });

});
```

When I check e.g. console on Chrome, get this data:

```
width: 1.3711566617862372 
height: 0.7488888888888889
```

But when I check this function on IE8, get this:

```
height: NaN 
 width: NaN
```

Searched on StackoverFlow but don't find solution. How can I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The innerWidth is **NOT** supported by **IE8** ,

Use this for all support ,

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's innerWidth support problem and solved by this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136089/1485921

So, added this function on my js file:

```
(function (window, html, body) {
    if (!window.innerWidth) Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerWidth', {
        get: function () { return html.clientWidth }
    });

    if (!window.innerHeight) Object.defineProperty(window, 'innerHeight', {
        get: function () { return html.clientHeight }
    });


}(this, document.documentElement, document.body));
```

Thank you!