# get window inner height accounting for x scroll bar height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the window inner height of the window, taking into account the x-scroll bar. but it seems `window.innerHeight` returns the same height regardless of whether or not the `x-scroll` bar is visible.

Is there another way of getting the the window height, which includes the `x-scroll` bar.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g75yg/1/) demonstrates that the value does not change when the scroll bar is added or removed.
There should be a difference, which is equal to the height of the scroll bar. I'll put the code for it below too. Thank you.

JavaScript:

```
$('#innerHeight').html(window.innerHeight);
$('input').click(function () {
    if ($('#bar').is(':visible')) {
        $('#bar').hide();
        $(this).val('show x-scroll bar');
        $('#innerHeight').html(inner.innerHeight);
    } else {
        $('#bar').show();
        $(this).val('hide x-scroll bar');
        $('#innerHeight').html(window.innerHeight);   
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="show x-scroll bar" /><br />
<div id="bar"></div>
<p>inner height: <a id = "innerHeight"> px</a></p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerHeight), `window.innerHeight` includes the height of the scrollbar.  I modified your example to use `$(window).height`(new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g75yg/2/)), which works if a newer version of jQuery is selected.  I stepped into jQuery 2.0.3, and `$(window)` is equivalent to `window.document.documentElement.clientHeight`.

You might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173236/window-innerheight-ie8-alternative) discussion useful.

Comment: `window.document.documentElement.clientHeight` Thank You! This is very useful snippet!