# IE8 Issue with fixed and absolute position

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a page with much content. When I open it I have a vertical scroll bar.
I have a small div that should stick to the right side and centered (vertically).
And when user scroll it should be in the same position never move just to be there in the center all the time.
And this work in chrome,ff but I have issues with ie8.
**Chrome**: div stick as it should be vertical center in the viewport of the browser.
**IE8**: div stick to the right but it use vertical center of the **whole content** and I need **just a viewport**. So if content is height=4000px in ie8 it centers it at 2000th pixel so user have to scroll to see it.
What I did wrong here?

```
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; 
top: 50%; 
right: 0;
```

Comment: can you link an example? ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J77Q7/

Comment: This works just fine for me [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J77Q7/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/VAV79/

Comment: Your code works for me with ie8

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.innerHeight ie8 alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173236/window-innerheight-ie8-alternative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with javascript. Here's an example, using jQuery, that I would try:

```
var calculatedTop = $(window).innerHeight() / 2;
$('#YourDiv').css('top', calculatedTop);
```

**Edit:** I've expanded this a bit to recalculate the top position when the user scrolls. Hopefully this helps with your IE8 problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var reposition = function() {
        var calculatedTop = $(window).innerHeight() / 2;
        calculatedTop += $(document).scrollTop();
        $('#YourDiv').css('top', calculatedTop);
    }

    // call reposition immediately on initial load
    reposition();

    // attach to scroll event
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        reposition();
    });
});
```

Comment: That works. I just used height() instead innerHeight().

Comment: Or vanilla JS : `var calculatedTop  = window.innerHeight / 2; var el = document.getElementById("elem"); el.style.top = calculatedTop  + "px";`

Comment: Aghh... in ie8 it is not in the center when scroll :(

Comment: You could attach to the scroll event, repositioning the top property each time. This should be set to the scrolled distance + the half the height of the current viewport.

Comment: Can you provide example?