# Create a tooltip in JavaScript without predefined HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a graph using canvas and would like to have a tooltip on a hover event over some of the plotted data. As far as i know canvas acts like a img tag and you can't really embed any html in a canvas element. Is it possible to create a tooltip that pops up when you hover over a specific coordinate, without any predefined HTML elements like a div or something?

My example:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    if(e.offsetX > set_x_cor && e.offsetY > set_y_cor){
        ///do code here//
    }
});
```

This event listener would be built up when all the graphs are drawn in canvas and is where the set coordinates will be set.

Comment: Check the answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064913/display-tooltip-in-canvas-graph

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for.