# d3 svg to fill screen

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to get the d3 svg visualization on this [page](http://opinion.berkeley.edu/mobile/) to fill the screen.

The HTML in my files is an empty div:

```
<div id='d3'>
</div>
```

When the page loads, it is populated with the following:

```
<svg width="1390" height="475"><g transform="translate(55,55)"> … </g></svg>
```

How can I tweak this width and height before hand to make it fill the page?

Comment: Have you tried setting the dimensions of the `div`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to D3! So can't give more info..but I found this JQuery Answer which you could use to first get at the width then just plug it in.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038765/709872

Apparently without JQuery to help it's more complicated! Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the screen with you svg maybe you can do this:

```
  var width = $(window).width();
  var height = $(window).height(); 

  var svgContainer = d3.select("#d3").append("svg")                                  
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Comment: this works without jQuery too `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`

Comment: and what if browser gets re-sized?

Comment: I guess you just need to add a listener and listen whenever those params change do the same again.