# How to find the dimensions inside of a web browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web

How do you find the dimensions inside of the web browser, [not the computer's window] using JavaScript. For example right now I am using Safari and Part of my page is covered by the Tabs etc. How do you find just the area inside that browser. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Comment: There are a tonne of examples of this throughout the web, not least here on SO. Did you research anything?

Comment: It's just `window.innerWidth*window.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. More explanation can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do it by: `$(window).width();`

Please take a look at [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code).

Comment: You're assuming the use of jQuery.

Comment: I am not using JQuery, apologies.