# Google Maps hide controls on small screens

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to hide Google Maps controls on small screens. By default Google Maps hides them at 320px width i think, but i need them to hide on bigger width, around 400px. [Here is one working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105189/hide-google-maps-controls-on-small-screens-mobiles-etc), but i am using different code so it is not working, i just get syntax errors. Here is my code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
     center: {
       lat: 52.00,
       lng: 10.00
     },
     zoom: 4,
      zoomControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
          },
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
          }
   });
```

This is code which captures width and disables controls, and it works with most Google Maps codes, but not with my...

```
$(window).width()       
var width = window.innerWidth;
 if(width < 400){
            mapOptions.mapTypeControl = false;
            mapTypeControl: false
            disableDefaultUI: true
            delete mapOptions.mapTypeControlOptions;
        }
```

Please show me how to combine these two codes so they work, i tryed doing something on my own, but im just getting syntax errors.

Comment: Use CSS mediaqueries?

Comment: Yep you are right, the simplest solution. I diggedd down and found this class gm-style-mtc and just put display:none with media query. Thx for suggestion, please write an answer so i can choose it as the best one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply hide it with media queries when the screen gets too small ;).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .gm-style-mtc {
        display:none;
    }   

}
```

Comment: **Never** use undocumented map properties and/or classnames. Use the documented map options and methods to hide the controls you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript `window.matchMedia()` method to match your media-query:

```
if(window.matchMedia("(your-media-query)").matches){
  mapOptions.mapTypeControl = false
  disableDefaultUI: true
  delete mapOptions.mapTypeControlOptions;
}
```

More infos here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia