# How to get browser width (not document/window)?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to find a solution to get the browser's width, not the document width.

```
window.innerWidth
```

This is the famous method to get it but I want to get the value inside an iframe (which is smaller than browser's viewport) but with the measures from browser (not the iframe). Like, testing in codepen or jsfiddle, I only get the width from result area.

```
browser (width: 1260px)
  > body
    > iframe (width: 260px)
    > iframe (width: 1000px)
      here, I want to get the browser value
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get browser width using JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code)

Comment: Please, read my question again. I add one more sentence, maybe I was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```js
console.log(window.outerWidth);
```

`window.innerWidth` is the width of the area within the browser. `window.outerWidth` is, unsurprisingly, the width of the browser itself.

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have something like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myFrame" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

To get the **iFrame** width:

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").width;
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#myFrame").width;
```

[iFrame reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

---

To get **browser** width

**javascript**

```
window.parent.width; // or innerwidth
```

[parent reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)

---

To get **screen** width

**javascript**

```
screen.width
```

[screen reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen)

You can mix all these techniques and get width of everything in your browser

Comment: I'm trying to avoid to get iframe width. Again, I want the browser width, not the document/window. So, in a codepen or jsfiddle, I would get all browser width, not the result/iframe/canvas areas.

Comment: so you have a browser window opend, inside that window a document and inside the document an iFrame right? What area do you want? and where do you want to display it?

Comment: Imagine a browser with 1260px width. Two iframes, 630px width each. Inside an iframe, I want to get the value from the browser (1260px).