# Creating a popup menu with bookmarklets

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

This is my first question, so please give me any pointers on how I could ask better ones.
Anyway, how would I make a togglable menu that displays links, that activates using a bookmarklet. I have tried to find answers, but all were fruitless. Would I need to create a new element for this?

Comment: I think [This would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why did you use the tag bookmarklet? Does it relate to your question? What sort of frameworks are you using? Please [edit] the question to add more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create the pop-up menu using vanilla JS. I also implemented drag functionality. The only thing this needs is to correctly set the position when a page is scrolled.

### DOM layout

The most important elements and styles below are required.

```html
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:2147483647">
  <div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position:relative; display:inline-block; left:0">Bookmarklet Links</div>
    <div style="position:relative; float:right">×</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Click the links to open a new tab!</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.bing.com" target="_blank">Bing</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://duckduckgo.com" target="_blank">DuckDuckGO</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can save the following bookmarklet:

```js
javascript:!function(){var c=0x1f4,d=0x12c,e='#AAA',f=0x1,g=0x20,h='#444',i='#FFF',j='Bookmarklet\x20Links',k=~~(document['documentElement']['clientWidth']/0x2-c/0x2),l=~~(document['documentElement']['clientHeight']/0x2-d/0x2),m=~~(0.8*g),n=document['createElement']('DIV');Object['assign'](n['style'],{'position':'absolute','left':k+'px','top':l+'px','zIndex':Number['MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'],'width':c+'px','height':d+'px','background':e,'border':f+'px\x20solid\x20black'});var o=document['createElement']('DIV');Object['assign'](o['style'],{'position':'relative','width':c+'px','height':g+'px','background':h,'borderBottom':f+'px\x20solid\x20black'});var p=document['createElement']('DIV');Object['assign'](p['style'],{'position':'relative','display':'inline-block','left':0x0,'width':~~(c-0x2*m)+'px','lineHeight':g+'px','color':i,'fontSize':~~(0.667*g)+'px','marginLeft':~~(m/0x3)+'px'}),p['textContent']=j;var q=document['createElement']('DIV'),r=~~((g-m)/0x2);Object['assign'](q['style'],{'position':'relative','float':'right','right':r+'px','top':r+'px','width':m+'px','height':m+'px','background':'#F00','border':f+'px\x20solid\x20black','color':'#FFF','lineHeight':m+'px','textAlign':'center','fontSize':m+'px','marginLeft':'auto','marginRight':0x0});var s=document['createElement']('DIV');Object['assign'](s['style'],{'padding':'1em'});var t=document['createElement']('P');t['textContent']='Click\x20the\x20links\x20to\x20open\x20a\x20new\x20tab!',s['appendChild'](t);var u=document['createElement']('UL');[{'name':'Google','url':'https://www.google.com'},{'name':'Bing','url':'https://www.bing.com'},{'name':'DuckDuckGO','url':'https://duckduckgo.com'}]['forEach'](c=>{var d=document['createElement']('LI'),e=document['createElement']('A');e['setAttribute']('href',c['url']),e['setAttribute']('target','_blank'),e['textContent']=c['name'],d['appendChild'](e),u['appendChild'](d);}),s['appendChild'](u),q['addEventListener']('click',function c(d){q['removeEventListener']('click',c,!0x1);o['removeChild'](q);n['removeChild'](o);n['removeChild'](s);document['body']['removeChild'](n);},!0x1),q['textContent']='×',o['appendChild'](p),o['appendChild'](q),n['appendChild'](o),n['appendChild'](s),document['body']['appendChild'](n),function(c){var d=function(c){var d=c['getBoundingClientRect'](),e=window['pageXOffset']||document['documentElement']['scrollLeft'],f=window['pageYOffset']||document['documentElement']['scrollTop'];return{'top':d['top']+f,'left':d['left']+e};}(c['parentElement']),e=!0x1,f={'x':0x0,'y':0x0},g={'x':d['left'],'y':d['top']};c['parentElement']['addEventListener']('mousedown',function(d){e=!0x0,f['x']=d['clientX'],f['y']=d['clientY'],c['parentElement']['style']['cursor']='move';}),c['parentElement']['addEventListener']('mouseup',function(d){e=!0x1,g['x']=parseInt(c['parentElement']['style']['left'])||0x0,g['y']=parseInt(c['parentElement']['style']['top'])||0x0,c['parentElement']['style']['cursor']='auto';}),document['addEventListener']('mousemove',function(d){if(!e)return;var h={'x':d['clientX']-f['x'],'y':d['clientY']-f['y']},i={'x':g['x']+h['x'],'y':g['y']+h['y']};i['x']<0x0?i['x']=0x0:i['x']+c['parentElement']['offsetWidth']>document['documentElement']['clientWidth']&&(i['x']=document['documentElement']['clientWidth']-c['parentElement']['offsetWidth']);i['y']<0x0?i['y']=0x0:i['y']+c['parentElement']['offsetHeight']>document['documentElement']['clientHeight']&&(i['y']=document['documentElement']['clientHeight']-c['parentElement']['offsetHeight']);c['parentElement']['style']['left']=i['x']+'px',c['parentElement']['style']['top']=i['y']+'px';});}(o);}(window);
```

### Method of minification and obfuscation

- I minified the code below using: https://javascript-minifier.com/
- I obfuscated the resulting minified code using: https://obfuscator.io/

For the obfuscator, I set "Identifier Names Generator" to "mangled" and checked "Rename Globals".

**Important:** Unselect "String Array" or you cannot add new link entries.

### Caveats

The script doesn't allow moving beyond the initial width and height. The following width and height methods from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038781/1762224) could be incorporated to fix this limitation.

---

### Source code

```js
(function(window) {
  var links = [{
    name: 'Google',
    url: 'https://www.google.com'
  }, {
    name: 'Bing',
    url: 'https://www.bing.com'
  }, {
    name: 'DuckDuckGO',
    url: 'https://duckduckgo.com'
  }];
  var props = {
    width: 500,
    height: 300,
    background: '#AAA',
    borderThickness: 1,
    headerHeight: 32,
    headerBackground: '#444',
    headerTitleColor: '#FFF',
    windowTitle: 'Bookmarklet Links'
  };
  var windowPosition = {
    left: ~~((document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2) - (props.width / 2)),
    top: ~~((document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - (props.height / 2)),
  }
  var btnSize = ~~(props.headerHeight * 0.8);
  var popupEl = document.createElement('DIV');
  Object.assign(popupEl.style, {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: windowPosition.left + 'px',
    top: windowPosition.top + 'px',
    zIndex: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    width: props.width + 'px',
    height: props.height + 'px',
    background: props.background,
    border: props.borderThickness + 'px solid black'
  });
  var popupHeader = document.createElement('DIV');
  Object.assign(popupHeader.style, {
    position: 'relative',
    width: (props.width) + 'px',
    height: props.headerHeight + 'px',
    background: props.headerBackground,
    borderBottom: props.borderThickness + 'px solid black'
  });
  var popupHeaderTitle = document.createElement('DIV');
  Object.assign(popupHeaderTitle.style, {
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'inline-block',
    left: 0,
    width: ~~(props.width - btnSize * 2) + 'px',
    lineHeight: props.headerHeight + 'px',
    color: props.headerTitleColor,
    fontSize: ~~(props.headerHeight * 0.667) + 'px',
    marginLeft: ~~(btnSize / 3) + 'px'
  });
  popupHeaderTitle.textContent = props.windowTitle;
  var closeButton = document.createElement('DIV');
  var margin = ~~((props.headerHeight - btnSize) / 2);
  Object.assign(closeButton.style, {
    position: 'relative',
    float: 'right',
    right: margin + 'px',
    top: margin + 'px',
    width: btnSize + 'px',
    height: btnSize + 'px',
    background: '#F00',
    border: props.borderThickness + 'px solid black',
    color: '#FFF',
    lineHeight: btnSize + 'px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: btnSize + 'px',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 0
  });
  var popupBody = document.createElement('DIV');
  Object.assign(popupBody.style, {
    padding: '1em'
  });
  var p = document.createElement('P');
  p.textContent = 'Click the links to open a new tab!';
  popupBody.appendChild(p);
  var listEl = document.createElement('UL');
  links.forEach(link => {
    var itemEl = document.createElement('LI');
    var anchorEl = document.createElement('A');
    anchorEl.setAttribute('href', link.url);
    anchorEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    anchorEl.textContent = link.name;
    itemEl.appendChild(anchorEl);
    listEl.appendChild(itemEl);
  });
  popupBody.appendChild(listEl);
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', destroyWindow, false);
  closeButton.textContent = '×';
  popupHeader.appendChild(popupHeaderTitle);
  popupHeader.appendChild(closeButton);
  popupEl.appendChild(popupHeader);
  popupEl.appendChild(popupBody);
  document.body.appendChild(popupEl);
  draggable(popupHeader);
  function destroyWindow(e) {
    closeButton.removeEventListener('click', destroyWindow, false);
    popupHeader.removeChild(closeButton);
    popupEl.removeChild(popupHeader);
    popupEl.removeChild(popupBody);
    document.body.removeChild(popupEl);
  }
  /* Source: https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/get-the-position-of-an-element-relative-to-the-document-24/ */
  function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
  }
  /* Source: https://gist.github.com/remarkablemark/5002d27442600510d454a5aeba370579 */
  function draggable(el) {
    var initialOffset = offset(el.parentElement);
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var currPos = { x : 0, y : 0 };
    var elPos = { x : initialOffset.left, y : initialOffset.top };
    el.parentElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
    function onMouseDown(event) {
      isMouseDown = true;
      currPos.x = event.clientX;
      currPos.y = event.clientY;
      el.parentElement.style.cursor = 'move';
    }
    el.parentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
    function onMouseUp(event) {
      isMouseDown = false;
      elPos.x = parseInt(el.parentElement.style.left) || 0;
      elPos.y = parseInt(el.parentElement.style.top) || 0;
      el.parentElement.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
    function onMouseMove(event) {
      if (!isMouseDown) return;
      var delta = { x : event.clientX - currPos.x, y: event.clientY - currPos.y };
      var pos = { x : elPos.x + delta.x, y : elPos.y + delta.y };
      if (pos.x < 0) {
        pos.x = 0;
      } else if (pos.x + el.parentElement.offsetWidth > document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
        pos.x = document.documentElement.clientWidth - el.parentElement.offsetWidth;
      }
      if (pos.y < 0) {
        pos.y = 0;
      } else if (pos.y + el.parentElement.offsetHeight > document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        pos.y = document.documentElement.clientHeight - el.parentElement.offsetHeight;
      }
      el.parentElement.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
      el.parentElement.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
    }
  }
})(window);
```

### Improving

You will notice that if your cursor goes off-screen while dragging (and you release the button) the window will be stuck in drag. You could detect this globally, but you will also need to figure out how re reinitialize the position to last known "good" position.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', onGlobalMouseUp);
function onGlobalMouseUp(event) {
  if (
    (event.clientX < 0 || event.clientX > document.documentElement.clientWidth) ||
    (event.clientY < 0 || event.clientY > document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  ) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      isMouseDown = false; // Draggged off-screen
      popupEl.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, don't spam the bookmarklet button, because it will create multiple instances of the same window. Code can be added to detect the presence of the window before creating a new one. Closing it could hide it, so it will just make the existing one visible again. Multiple windows will break the close listener.