# Looking for alternative aprroch to window.screen.width and window.screen.height

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a different approach to find browser resolution. As of now, we are using
`${window.screen.width}x${window.screen.height}` to find resolution.

In a few cases, it is giving a response as undefinedxundefined for browsers in ios/android.
Is there any other approach to capture width and height

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038727/how-to-get-browser-width-using-javascript-code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can:

```
document.body.scrollWidth,
document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
document.body.offsetWidth,
document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Please note that some modern devices have a density pixel rate of at least 2. So a browser screen size of 375px ends up being 750px (375px x 2) in your javascript.